# Disable coupons field from checkout page when order total amout is less than $500

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I am working on `Drupal commerce` site. Using `commerce_discount_extra` and `commerce_discount` for discount and coupon code.

I just want to display Coupon apply filed into checkout page while the total amount of order will be >=$500. Below $500 the coupons field will not display into checkout page.

So can anyone please tell me how can I disable the Coupons fields from checkout page when the order amount will be less than $500?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works.

```
function module_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_state['order']->commerce_order_total['und'][0]['amount'] < 500) {
    unset($form['commerce_coupon']); // enter coupon form name
  }
}
```